# Javascript put drop down list in dialog popup and return value

Tags: javascript

As in topic I would like to put in drop down list in dialog javascript pop up and return value.

Thanks for help.

Comment: what exactly do you want? Please elaborate

Comment: For example I have dict_A = {'name':'b', 'surname':{'d', 'e'}}. I would like to show pop up window where there are two drop down fields with dict values, one called dict first key, second with dict second key. Then user chooses values for fields and returns values. Thanks